# How many times can I apply for a Marie Curie Individual Fellowship?

Tags: postdocs, funding, europe, marie-curie

It is not clear to me how many times one can apply for a Marie Curie Individual Fellowship. I was told that I can apply for such fundings only two times. Is that information true? I couldn't find any place where this is mentioned. Can someone confirm that?

Comment: I can't answer, but It may be relevant whether your first application was successful or not. Want to edit that into your question?

Comment: [this page](https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/actions/postdoctoral-fellowships#:~:text=As%20from%202022%2C%20resubmission%20restrictions,budget%20available%20under%20the%20call.) says that you have to score above 70 to resubmit